# Django runserver isn't updating after .py file changes

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and using manage.py runserver for a live server.  When I make changes to html and css files in my project, I only have to refresh the web page to see the changes, but when I make changes to the .py files (views.py or urls.py for example) I have to stop and restart the live server manually before refreshing the web page to see the changes.  Is there a setting that I can change to avoid this manual reset?

I am using visual studio code in windows and the actual command I'm using is:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I've added the project to github if anyone wants to have a look:  [myproject link](https://github.com/JonathanDPotter/myproject.git)

It is a runthrough of this tutorial:
[Python Backend Web Development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBzwzrDvZ18&t=19722s)

Comment: Is `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py? If not, that is the reason.

Comment: Did you make an app and not add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list?

Comment: DEBUG = True is in my settings.py

Comment: My app has been added to the INSTALLED_APPS list.